# How to query data from yesterday in moment js or date?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have data in my database that I want to query thats from yesterday
when i do

```
momentendYest', moment().startOf('day').subtract(1,'day').toDate()
```

its today 7am? i dont understand

I'm trying to do something like this :

```
    const yesterdayCoins = await Coin.find({
  category: {
    $regex: new RegExp(fullName, "i"),
  },
  createdAt: {
    $gte: startYest,
    $lt: endYest,
  },
```

what can i do to make the date from yesterday at 12am to 11:59pm ?

Answer (score 0):

Something likes works with plain javascript.

```js
const today = new Date()

const year = today.getFullYear()
const month = today.getMonth()
const day = today.getDate()

const yesterday = new Date(year, month, day-1, 23,59,00)

console.log(yesterday)
```

We make a date for today, get the year, month and then subtract one from day, then hardcode the time.

I wasn't sure if you wanted at midnight or not. If you do, just skip the time parameters.

Comment: Why does today give me 7:00:00

Comment: Does it give you 7 today when you run that snippet?

Comment: it says octal literals are not allowed in strict mode